# Bachelor's degree vs undergraduate program

Tags: word-usage

Good morning!

May I employ "bachelor's degree" as a synonym for "undergraduate program"?

For instance, is it correct to say that I am "currently enrolled in a bachelor's degree"? Or, otherwise, that I have learned a lot during my "bachelor's degree"?

Comment: Please explain the context. In different countries different conventions apply concerning how these terms are properly used. What country and precise qualification are you asking about?

Comment: In the United States, for instance. I do not know if I can use the term "bachelor's degree" to refer to the period of 3/4 years in which I attended classes in order to obtain a diploma. Another example: "during my bachelor's degree I have learned many things". Does this construction sound natural?

Comment: A degree is the qualification which is awarded at the end of your course of study, not the course itself. In the UK, you could say "I am studying _for_ my bachelor's degree".

Comment: @KateBunting Or "I learned a lot on my Batchelor's degree course". As you say the degree is the qualification, not the course of study leading to it.

Answer (score 2):

In the US, The four year degree that follows high school and precedes a graduate degree is the Bachelors degree and is also known as an undergraduate degree. Bachelors and Undergraduate are often used interchangeably, but as @KateBunting noted, a bachelors is the degree, not the course of study, so;

you wouldn't say,

> "I'm currently enrolled in a bachelor's degree."

you could say,

> "I'm pursuing a Bachelors degree in Architecture."
>
> "I'm pursuing an undergraduate degree in Architecture."

There are some differences in usage when it comes to describing your course of study.

you could say,

> "I have learned a lot during my undergraduate studies."

you wouldn't say,

> "I have learned a lot during my bachelors studies." (I don't believe this is technically incorrect, but it would sound odd to the average US English speaker)

Comment: I’d just add that that in ordinary conversation both “undergraduate” and “bachelors” might often be omitted, when taking about your course of study, since they are understood from the context. For example, “What have you been doing since we left high school?” “I’m studying for a degree in Architecture.” (It is understood that the degree is at bachelor level and that they are an undergraduate.)